# NotSupportedException is thrown when trying to save Emitted assembly

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit, system.reflection

http://pastebin.com/n6G1jTHQ
My code creates a new assembly and module, and then emits a class `SWT`(within a new assembly) that should be exactly the same as `SWTTFields`class.
Line 137, saves the assembly/module into a `.dll`, `myAsmBuilder.Save("ModuleOne.dll");` throws the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Type 'SWT' was not completed.

Why I am getting this error ? What is missing in my emitted class ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call the [TypeBuilder.CreateType Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each TypeBuilder before saving the File.